# Cannot get file created with fopen

Tags: ftp, download, fopen

I've created a file with fopen as so

```
            $string = '<?php
    define ("DB_HOST", "'. $_POST["dbhost"]. '");
    define ("DB_USER", "'. $_POST["dbuname"]. '");
    define ("DB_PASS","'. $_POST["dbpass"]. '");
    define ("DB_NAME","'. $_POST["dbname"]. '")
    ?>';
        $confile = "../lib/con.php";
        if (!file_exists($confile)) {
            $fp = fopen($confile, "x") or die("can't open file ".$confile);
            fwrite($fp, $string);
            fclose($fp);
        } else {
            $fp = fopen($confile, "w") or die("can't open file ".$confile);
            fwrite($fp, $string);
            fclose($fp);                
        }
```

However now if I try to download the file using Dreamweaver or Filezilla it won't download the file unless I rename it. Can anyone work out what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Doesnt seem to be a problem with your code, seems to be a problem with dreamweaver or filezilla.

Comment: @DWolf thanks I actually just decided to try naming my file `conn.php` instead of `con.php` and it worked for some reason. Will post answer when the site lets me. :)

Comment: I just read somewhere that con.txt or any file type may be regarded as a reserve word. so try not to use con.. Update your post if conn solved your problem :)

Comment: @DWolf would you mind posting that as an answer and I'll tick it for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con in a web server sense is considered a reserve, to some web hosts, and that when writing to a file named con, it sometimes fail, if you rename the the file to conn.php it should work.